# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, rmi, noclassdeffounderror

I have no idea of why this is having a runtime error, I have googled the problem and it says that a class that was available during compile time is no longer available at run time.

This is the code:

```
package examples.RMIShape;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
//import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class ShapeListServer {
    public static void main(String args[]){
//      System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        System.out.println("Main OK");
        try{
            ShapeList aShapelist = new ShapeListServant();
            System.out.println("After create");
            String registryURL = "rmi://localhost:" + "/ShapeList";
            startRegistry();
            Naming.rebind(registryURL, aShapelist);
            System.out.println("ShapeList server ready");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ShapeList server main " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // This method starts a RMI registry on the local host, if it
    // does not already exists at the specified port number.
    private static void startRegistry()throws RemoteException{
        Registry registry;
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.list( );  // This call will throw an exception
            // if the registry does not already exist
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            // No valid registry at that port.
            System.out.println ("RMI registry cannot be located at port " + Registry.REGISTRY_PORT );
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
            System.out.println("RMI registry created at port " + Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        }
    } // end startRegistry
}
```

Comment: Google says it correctly, just find the answers for these questions and you should be good. For which class you are getting this error? In which jar that class is present? Finally is that jar in your classpath?

Comment: Please post the complete error message including stack trace; it tells you also what class is missing. You have to make sure that class is in the classpath when you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

> I have googled the problem and it says that a class that was available during compile time is no longer available at run time.

That's not correct. That would cause ClassNotFoundException. This one has several causes, but the most common one is that the class in the file isn the class implied by the filename and directory hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

Basicall java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

following links will be helpful. This links will guide you slove issue.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: I don't want to argue with but whatever I have written there is from oracle java doc and you said "I have googled the problem and it says that a class that was available during compile time is no longer available at run time." and if you go to link : http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html you will "What is reason of NoClassDefFoundError in Java" they clearly says "NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time" Please have look. Thanks for comment

Comment: I didn't say any of that. That was a quote from the OP. I'm aware of what the Javadoc says and it isn't correct.